# Audio and video desynchronized

Tags: sound, video, vlc

Using VLC or Videos or a flash animation embebbed in a webpage, I always get the video out of sync with the audio.

This has been an issue for some time and appears to get more obvious. I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with a Intel NUC5PPYH.

It is not a computer perfomance problem, because the hardware is quite capable of handling video.

This appears to be a software problem.
Can anyone help me discovering where the problem is?

Comment: So YouTube has the same issue?

Comment: Don't know. It is very rare to watch youtube and when it happens if only for few seconds. But watching the national TV online has the same issue. They use Flash.